# Access 2nd-story burst hydronic pipe through ceiling or floor?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, ceiling, floor

We had a freeze which caused one or more bursts in our hydronic heating system pipes. We know that there is one burst in a radiator, but there may be others, according to the contractors. If there is a burst where the pipe goes under the hardwood floor, would the HVAC contractors likely access the pipe by cutting through the floor, or through the ceiling of the story below?

We ask so we can best prepare the house for the HVAC contractor visit. We'd like to be able put things on the floor above the pipes, but will keep the area below them clear.

(I did try to ask the HVAC service company, but was unable to speak to an actual contractor.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally they would access from below - plaster/drywall is easier to both open and repair than flooring.